# "Fino a quando verrà" o "fino a quando non verrà"?

Tags: negation

Ho sentito dire più di una volta la frase seguente in aereo prima del decollo:

"Tenere allacciate le cinture fino a quando l'apposito segnale verrà spento".

A me suona strana, io direi invece:

"Tenere allacciate le cinture fino a quando l'apposito segnale non verrà spento".

Quale delle due è corretta? Per me, la prima frase suona strana perché il "fino a quando" dà l'idea di continuità di un'azione che sta avvenendo adesso (il segnale è acceso). "Fino a quando il segnale resta acceso" suona bene, ma "fino a quando il segnale verrà spento" suona male per me. "Fino a quando il segnale (che adesso è acceso) non verrà spento" suona bene.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @sam81!

Comment: If you are satisfied with one of the answers to your question, please consider the option to "accept" an answer by clicking a checkmark next to that answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il Treccani, alla voce [*finché*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/finche/) (che non è altro che una contrazione di *fino a che*), prevede due casi: con una condizione (non negata) che indica il periodo ("finché c'è vita c'è speranza"), e con una condizione negata che indica il suo termine ("non ti muovere finché non lo dico io"). Ma questo significa che, per *finché*, Treccani prevede un solo caso. Per esempio, in "finché non si spegne il segnale", la condizione che è verificata durante tutto il periodo è il **non** spegnersi del segnale. Il caso previsto è soltanto quello in cui la condizione sia verificata per tutto il periodo in questione e non più verificata al suo termine.

Alla voce [*fino<sup>2</sup>*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fino2/) invece il Treccani dice una cosa diversa (punto **a** della voce): *fino a* è seguito dal punto (temporale) d'arrivo. Quando questo punto è espresso tramite una condizione, la condizione è esattamente la negazione logica della condizione di cui alla voce *finché*.

Mi spiego meglio: esistono due tipi di condizione, l'una la negazione logica dell'altra:

- La condizione che è verificata per tutto il periodo in questione e che non è più verificata quando il periodo termina (chiamiamola **condizione di continuazione**)
- La condizione che si verifica nel momento in cui il periodo in questione termina, e non prima (chiamiamola **condizione di terminazione**)

Secondo il Treccani, con *finché* va usata la condizione di continuazione, mentre con *fino a* va usato il momento di termine, che, visto come condizione, è la condizione di terminazione. La frase corretta sarebbe quindi "Tenere allacciate le cinture fino a quando l'apposito segnale verrà spento".

L'italiano corrente, però, non è necessariamente quello descritto dal Treccani (basta leggere l'ultima frase della voce [*fintantoché*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fintantoche/) per convincersene), e, di fatto, *fino a* viene usato sia con la condizione di continuazione che con quella di terminazione, risolvendo l'ambiguità in base ad altre informazioni. Per esempio, la frase "leggo fino a quando resto solo" può significare che quando arriva qualcuno smetto di leggere, oppure che leggo in compagnia fino al momento in cui resto solo.

Probabilmente, anzi, una condizione è più spesso interpretata come condizione di continuazione, come nel caso di *finché*. Per questo motivo, secondo me, a te la frase suona meglio con l'inserimento del *non*. E per lo stesso motivo, la seconda interpretazione della frase "leggo fino a quando resto solo" è più comunemente resa come "leggo fino a quando non resto solo".

Personalmente, invece, e non perché mi voglia attenere a quanto dice il Treccani, preferisco interpretare la condizione di *fino a* come condizione di terminazione. In altre parole, preferisco interpretare "quando l'apposito segnale verrà spento" come il momento in cui ha termine il periodo in cui vanno tenute allacciate le cinture. Mi sembra più coerente con i casi in cui a *fino a* segue il termine, come in *fino alla fine*.

Tu invece, e credo che tu stia con la maggioranza degli italiani (non ho nulla da ridire, insomma), preferisci interpretare la condizione come condizione di continuazione, il che comporta la necessità di negarla tramite un *non*.

Ma c'è dell'altro: il *non* viene inserito ormai automaticamente (quando è possibile, naturalmente), anche quando la frase risultante, a rigor di logica, perde di senso. Questo avviene, a mio parere, a causa delle frequenza con cui capita che una condizione di terminazione debba essere convertita in una condizione di continuazione.

La frase "Tenere allacciate le cinture fino al momento in cui l'apposito segnale non verrà spento" è comprensibile a tutti e non pare errata. Ma qual è questo momento, il "momento in cui l'apposito segnale **non** verrà spento"?

---

#### EDIT

Mi rendo conto che questa risposta andrebbe riscritta per due motivi:

1. è troppo lunga
2. non tiene conto del fatto che l'inserimento di un *non* che non cambia il significato di una frase è un fenomeno linguistico riconosciuto e codificato, detto [non pleonastico](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_pleonastico)<sup>*</sup>

<sub>* probabilmente lo ignoravo perché il tedesco, la mia lingua "scolastica", non ce l'ha</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Credo che in casi come questo, dove la frasi di per sé sono ambigue in primo luogo, sia necessario fare riferimento all'intuizione più che a una regola vera e propria;

Sono, ovviamente, grammaticalmente, tutte e due corrette; *credo* che la differenza sia da ricercarsi piuttosto in cosa debba essere dedotto da ognuna delle due forme:

- "Tenere allacciate le cinture fino a quando l'apposito segnale verrà spento" -> l'azione di tenere allacciate le cinture deve perdurare *fino al momento in cui* l'apposito segnale viene spento;
- "Tenere allacciate le cinture fino a quando l'apposito segnale non verrà spento" -> l'azione di tenere allacciate le cinture deve perdurare *per tutto il tempo durante il quale* l'apposito segnale non "viene" (ovvero "è") spento;

Ovvero semplicemente le due si riferiscono, non grammaticalmente, ma intuitivamente, a due momenti, se si vuole, complementari e opposti, perché il primo è il momento in cui l'azione deve cessare, mentre il secondo è il momento in cui l'azione deve perdurare; questo porta all'ambiguità "logica" di entrambe, dove una è negata e l'altra non lo è;

Per venire alla domanda vera e propria: sono corrette tutte e due; semplicemente si riferiscono, implicitamente, a due momenti nel tempo diversi.